# UITableViewCell design changes when selecting

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When I select a cell using the cell selection button , the design of the cell changes.
There is a blue line in the bottom (may be due to selection highlighting)
and the round corner changes to light blue.

Please suggest ways to solve this issue. I don't want these two effects.

[image]

Comment: Please supply the code you’re using to set up the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: I had done this before but it does half the work. I mean cell is not highlighted by setting selection style to none it is fine . But the red circle on the left is also losing its functionality.